# Can't able to open this file "admin://etc/sysctl.conf"? It says, "Unable to handle admin location"

Tags: swap

[image]

As u can see. At first its permission denied . And now "Unable to handle "admin: " locations.

Comment: From 60 to 10 is a decrease in swappiness. Is this what you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `admin://` to the beginning of the full path to your preferred file to use the GVfs admin backend.

Since you're trying to open the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file, you need to run

```
gedit admin:///etc/sysctl.conf
```

Comment: Well i did "gedit admin:///etc/sysctl.conf" without doing anything. It didn't do anything.

Comment: same issue. Unable to handle admin....

Comment: @Prabeshbhattarai Then you probably don't have `gvfs-backends`  installed. Install it first by running `sudo apt install gvfs-backends`, after that run `gedit admin:///etc/sysctl.conf`.

Comment: The gvfs is already installed. It says, "** (gedit:20502): WARNING **: 15:38:54.588: The specified location is not mounted"

Comment: is "admin" is a string that may differ from user to another ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know what was wrong but going manually through `cd /etc` and using `sudo nano sysctl.conf` to edit solved my issue.

Comment: You can use `sudo -e /etc/sysctl.conf`. The `-e` flag will use a default editor